# Telegraf plugins - Telegraf send data to influxdb only for one plugin

Tags: influxdb, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin, telegraf-output-plugins

Im new here, I have an issue with one plugin,

So im using telegraf to get data from ipmi sensor, and it’s working I can see that in Grafana dashboard via InfluxDB,

so until here everything is working correctly,
I added another input plugin to my telegraf.conf : telegraf-speedtest/speedtest.conf at master · Derek-K/telegraf-speedtest · GitHub

Once im checking telegraf -test , I can see that the first plugin(ipmi sensor) is OK and second plugin (speedtest) is OK as well.

But speedtest measurements are not stored in the influxdb I check it using

```
root@d5c51db15460:/# influx -execute ‘show measurements’ -database ‘telegraph’
name: measurements
name

ipmi_sensor
```

Here as you can see there is only the ipmi_sensor :( .
Telegraf is restarted already, and both plugins are working with -test
im not sure where is the issue, I appreciate your help guys

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The telegraf `--test` option does not send data to outputs. I would suggest using the `--once` option if you want to ensure data is making it to outputs as well.